# Migrate to VS2013 Comparison operator Error C2678:binary '==' no operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2005, comparison-operators

I have below code works fine in visual studio 2005. But get compile errors when migrating to visual studio 2013.

```
// Check if the row in the file starts with a double value
bool RowReader::isDouble(std::wstring value)
{
    double testValue;
    std::wistringstream in(value);
    in.setf(std::ios::dec, std::ios::basefield);

    if((in >> testValue) == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

The error is:

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_istream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Any help ? I am very new to this. 
1. Is testValue initial value 0 ?
2. Why if it's equal to NULL if the first character is not double ?
3. How to fix this compile error?

Comment: Stricter rules in C++11, you can't use a deleted function.  Impossible to guess at the intent, just delete it since it will never return false.

Comment: @HansPassant   Could you please explain a little bit more ? I'm very new to this code.

Comment: That line of code is nonsense, neither the stream nor the double can ever be NULL.  You need to delete it.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I have posted the answer for this. the original code was written by other people.. It was not easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. See below code:

```
bool isDouble(std::wstring value)
{
    wchar_t * endptr = 0;
    wcstod(value.c_str(), &endptr);
    if (*endptr != '\0' || endptr == value.c_str()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```